# Javascript/jQuery: toggle (vjs-fade-out) when userActive value changes (video.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, video.js

I am using *video.js* to create a player that needs to be played on multiple devices. I have an custom (return to menu) button that is placed on top right corner of the video. I need to add/remove (`vjs-fade-out`) class to it according to the user interaction (`mouseover`, `mouseout`, `tap`, `playe`, `pasue`, ...).
I have this so far that has some bugs...

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-btn">
  <a href="../index.html">
    <img src="../img/back.svg" width="50">
  </a>
</div>

<video id="myPlayer" class="video-js vjs-sublime-skin" width="1024px" height="768px" controls autoplay preload data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
  <source src="../video/test.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  <track class="caption" kind="captions" src="../video/test.vtt" type="text/plain" srclang="en" label="English" default />
</video>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-btn {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
videojs("myPlayer").on('mouseout', function() {
  $(".menu-btn").addClass('vjs-fade-out');
});

videojs("myPlayer").on('mouseover', function() {
  $(".menu-btn").removeClass('vjs-fade-out');
});

videojs("myPlayer").on('tap', function() {
  if (videojs("myPlayer").userActive()) {
    $(".menu-btn").removeClass('vjs-fade-out');
  } else {
    //do nothing
  }
}, 1500);
```

and I want to change it to something like this using `userActive`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (videojs("myPlayer").userActive()) {
    $(".menu-btn").removeClass('vjs-fade-out');
  } else {
    $(".menu-btn").addClass('vjs-fade-out');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer

```js
myPlayer.on("useractive", function() {
  $(".menu-btn").removeClass("vjs-fade-out");
});

myPlayer.on("userinactive", function() {
  $(".menu-btn").addClass("vjs-fade-out");
});
```